# GRADLE Build Error : Permission Denied: No further information

Tags: java, gradle, vpn, intellij-14

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: no further information
        at `sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:111)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.tryConnect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:81)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector.connect(TcpOutgoingConnector.java:54)`
        ... 29 more
```

This error occurs when I connect to VPN, if not connect it works fine.
I need to use VPN for new libraries, Please suggest the best answer to resolve this.
Disabling firewall does not work for me
placing gradle.properties in `.gradle` folder did not worked.
adding _JAVA_OPTION allowing ipv4 stack also did not worked.`gradle build`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue will resolved by directing the cacerts with all installed certificates in to your gradle.properties. No JAVA Args required.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this answer? As written, it does not provide enough information for me to understand how to resolve the problem.